# logic behind php array and strlen

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble understanding this piece of code.

```
$txt = 'John ';
$txt[10] = 'Doe ';

echo $txt;
echo "<br>";
echo strlen($txt);
```

The result are:

```
John D
11
```

Can someone explain  why the answer is **John D**?

Comment: Basically, there is *no* logic in this piece of code. That's all

Answer (score 1):

The PHP warning message says:

> Only the first byte will be assigned to the string offset.

So as it does not cast to an array you are putting the `D` on the 11th place (count from zero). That's why the string is 11 bytes long. A byte index can only access one character.